# How to declare a global array within an exec in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, linux, exec, global

I'm writing a js script to locate all pid files on a server, extract the pids and then run ' ps -fp {pid} ' on each of it and extract the memory usages.

This is what I've got so far:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('(cd ~/; find . -type f -name "*.pid" )', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      return 1
    }
    var fileps = stdout.toString().split('\n');
    fileps.pop()  
    var pidsarr = new Array;
    
    function getpid(path) {
    var command = `(cd ~/; cat ${path} )`;
    exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          return 1
        }
        pid = parseInt(stdout.toString());
        pidsarr.push(pid);
    });
    }

    fileps.forEach(getpid);    
    console.log(pidsarr); 
});
```

The issue is pidsarr is not getting updated, probably since it's not declared global or something to do with exec not allowing to write to external objects.

Any way to get my pidsarr array to get appended each run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pidsarr` *is* appended to for each run. However, you just schedule the runs in the background and don't wait for them to finish, so you don't see the final value.

You can verify this with a `setTimeout(() => console.log(pidsarr), 1000);`

To make it wait, you can either rewrite in terms of `execSync`, or have `getpid` return a Promise, then wait for all the promises to resolve:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('(cd ~/;  find . -type f -name "*.pid")', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      return 1
    }
    var fileps = stdout.toString().split('\n');
    fileps.pop()
    var pidsarr = new Array();

   function getpid(path) {
      var command = `(cd ~/; cat ${path} )`;
      return new Promise((resolve, fail) => {
        exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (error) {
            fail();
          }
          pid = parseInt(stdout.toString());
          pidsarr.push(pid);
          resolve();
        });
      })
    }

    Promise.all(fileps.map(getpid)).then(() => console.log(pidsarr));
});
```

Note that it's bad practice to invoke `find` and `cat` like this. It's faster, more robust, and more portable to use `glob` and `fs` to find and read files without external tools.

Comment: Thank you so much this really informative answer!!!!!!!!!!!  I figured usind find and cat would probably not be the most efficient way. I will take a look at glob and fs as well. (I'm pretty much a noob with linux since I started last week :( )